# Conditionally extracting data from long lists

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I need to make a fit on a small part of my data list. To do so I need to extract data setting a condition.

Example:
From the list below I would like to create a new list that contains only data whose first element (my x variable) is in between -0.4096 and -0.4089

```
datalist = {{-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}, {-0.4095, 0.175537}, {-0.40945, 0.130859},
            {-0.4094, 0.157714}, {-0.40935, 0.121826}, {-0.4093, 0.137207},
            {-0.40925, 0.135009}, {-0.4092, 0.118774}, {-0.40915, 0.126831},
            {-0.4091, 0.127441}, {-0.40905, 0.14392}, {-0.409, 0.145507},
            {-0.40895, 0.16455}, {-0.4089, 0.145141}, {-0.40885, 0.138305},
            {-0.4088, 0.141845}, {-0.40875, 0.145874}, {-0.4087, 0.125122},
            {-0.40865, 0.140747}, {-0.4086, 0.124145}, {-0.40855, 0.146362},
            {-0.4085, 0.139892}}
```

Take in mind that my actual data lists are much longer that the above one.

Thank you very much for your help!

Alberto

Comment: try `Select[-0.4089<=#[[1]]<=-0.4096&]@datalist`

Comment: Your `Example:` paragraph actually contains all the Wolfram Language symbols of the solution you are looking for: `datalist // Select[First /* Between[{-0.4089, -0.4096}]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datalist = {{-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}, {-0.4095, 
    0.175537}, {-0.40945, 0.130859}, {-0.4094, 0.157714}, {-0.40935, 
    0.121826}, {-0.4093, 0.137207}, {-0.40925, 0.135009}, {-0.4092, 
    0.118774}, {-0.40915, 0.126831}, {-0.4091, 0.127441}, {-0.40905, 
    0.14392}, {-0.409, 0.145507}, {-0.40895, 0.16455}, {-0.4089, 
    0.145141}, {-0.40885, 0.138305}, {-0.4088, 0.141845}, {-0.40875, 
    0.145874}, {-0.4087, 0.125122}, {-0.40865, 0.140747}, {-0.4086, 
    0.124145}, {-0.40855, 0.146362}, {-0.4085, 0.139892}};
```

Try this:

```
Select[datalist, -0.496 <= #[[1]] <= 0.4089 &]

(* {{-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}, {-0.4095, 
  0.175537}, {-0.40945, 0.130859}, {-0.4094, 0.157714}, {-0.40935, 
  0.121826}, {-0.4093, 0.137207}, {-0.40925, 0.135009}, {-0.4092, 
  0.118774}, {-0.40915, 0.126831}, {-0.4091, 0.127441}, {-0.40905, 
  0.14392}, {-0.409, 0.145507}, {-0.40895, 0.16455}, {-0.4089, 
  0.145141}, {-0.40885, 0.138305}, {-0.4088, 0.141845}, {-0.40875, 
  0.145874}, {-0.4087, 0.125122}, {-0.40865, 0.140747}, {-0.4086, 
  0.124145}, {-0.40855, 0.146362}, {-0.4085, 0.139892}}   *)
```

or this

```
datalist /. {x_, y_} /; x < -0.496 || x > -0.4089 -> Nothing

(* {{-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}, {-0.4095, 
  0.175537}, {-0.40945, 0.130859}, {-0.4094, 0.157714}, {-0.40935, 
  0.121826}, {-0.4093, 0.137207}, {-0.40925, 0.135009}, {-0.4092, 
  0.118774}, {-0.40915, 0.126831}, {-0.4091, 0.127441}, {-0.40905, 
  0.14392}, {-0.409, 0.145507}, {-0.40895, 0.16455}, {-0.4089, 
  0.145141}} *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks!!! Both work exactly as I wanted

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility using `Pick`:

```
Pick[datalist,Unitize[Clip[datalist[[All,1]], {-0.4096, -0.4089},{0,0}]],1]
```

> {{-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}, {-0.4095, 0.175537}, {-0.40945, 0.130859}, {-0.4094, 0.157714}, {-0.40935, 0.121826}, {-0.4093, 0.137207}, {-0.40925, 0.135009}, {-0.4092, 0.118774}, {-0.40915, 0.126831}, {-0.4091, 0.127441}, {-0.40905, 0.14392}, {-0.409, 0.145507}, {-0.40895, 0.16455}, {-0.4089, 0.145141}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{99., 4.}, {-99., 5.}, {-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}};
```

Using [SequenceSplit](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceSplit.html) (new in 11.3)

```
First @ SequenceSplit[list, {{a_, _} /; ! Between[a, {-0.496, 0.4089}]}]
```

{{-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}}

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[ a: {b_, _} /; Between[b, {-0.496, 0.4089}] :> a] @ list
```

{{-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}}

`SequenceSplit` is currently (V 13.3) slow with long lists.

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Interval` functionality:**

```
Clear["Global`"];
datalist = {{-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}, {-0.4095, 
    0.175537}, {-0.40945, 0.130859}, {-0.4094, 0.157714}, {-0.40935, 
    0.121826}, {-0.4093, 0.137207}, {-0.40925, 0.135009}, {-0.4092, 
    0.118774}, {-0.40915, 0.126831}, {-0.4091, 0.127441}, {-0.40905, 
    0.14392}, {-0.409, 0.145507}, {-0.40895, 0.16455}, {-0.4089, 
    0.145141}, {-0.40885, 0.138305}, {-0.4088, 0.141845}, {-0.40875, 
    0.145874}, {-0.4087, 0.125122}, {-0.40865, 0.140747}, {-0.4086, 
    0.124145}, {-0.40855, 0.146362}, {-0.4085, 0.139892}};

int = Interval[{-0.4089, -0.4096}];

Pick[datalist, IntervalMemberQ[int, First@#] & /@ datalist]

Select[IntervalMemberQ[int, First@#] &][datalist]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}, {-0.4095,
> 0.175537}, {-0.40945, 0.130859}, {-0.4094, 0.157714}, {-0.40935,
> 0.121826}, {-0.4093, 0.137207}, {-0.40925, 0.135009}, {-0.4092,
> 0.118774}, {-0.40915, 0.126831}, {-0.4091, 0.127441}, {-0.40905,
> 0.14392}, {-0.409, 0.145507}, {-0.40895, 0.16455}, {-0.4089,
> 0.145141}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{99., 4.}, {-99., 5.}, {-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[list, {a_, _} /; ! Between[a, {-0.496, 0.4089}]]

(*{{-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {s : {a_, _} /; Between[a, {-0.496, 0.4089}]} :> s]

(*{{-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}}*)
```

Or using `Pick` and `IntervalIntersection`:

```
int = Interval[{-0.496, 0.4089}];

Pick[#, IntervalIntersection[int, Interval @@ #] =!= Interval[] & /@ #] &@list

(*{{-0.4096, 0.15332}, {-0.40955, 0.13269}}*)
```